# Stack trace of UnhandledException

Tags: c#, uwp, unhandled-exception, pdb-files, bugsnag

I want to store the `UnhandledException` of my UWP app in `Bugsnag`. There is a subscription to the UnhandledException event In `App.XAML.cs`.

```
UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
```

When the event fired we send an exception to Bugsnag using Notify method.

```
private async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if(e is InternetConnectionExeption)
        await AsyncMethod();
    BugsnagClient.Notify(e.Exception, Severiry.Error);
}
```

In Debug mode We get the cause of the exception in `e.Message`.
But in release mode, We get  the following:
[image]
Using this stacktrace I can`t analyze and understand the cause of the exception.

For release mode in the .csproj file I added  the following:

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
```

In the popup of creating a package, I set the checkbox.
[image]
But the result is the same. The result is also the same when I run the application in release mode (without creating app package)

The question is. How I can get a stack trace in detail? I would like to know the method name where exceptions were thrown.

Comment: What might happen if the Notify() method itself throws an exception?  Well, that.

Comment: @HansPassant  What do you mean? The question is why the UnhandledExceptionEventArgs .Exception.Stacktrace==null?

Comment: I see a stack trace with 3 methods, that doesn't suggest null.  Sounds to me you haven't yet reasoned-out what that stack trace says, Notify() itself throwing an exception.  No idea why, might have something to do with the way BugsnagClient is configured.

Comment: @HansPassant Ooo yes, you are right. May be due to stack trace == null?  I set a breakpoint before and after the `if` statement. before `if` there is `e.Exeption.Stacktrace`, but after `if` `e.Exception.Stacktrace==null`. Can it relate to `async`, `await`?